# I'm on trouble to solve the error "Cannot find a setter ..."

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

This is the error message.

```
Cannot find a setter for <xxx.xxx.xxx.view.customview.ImageView resource> that accepts parameter type 'java.lang.String'
```

I use this customview on the layout file

layoutA.xml

```kotlin
<xxx.xxx.xxx.view.customview.ImageView
resource="@{data.imageUrl}"
```

data class is like down below. I'm going to add image URL for `imageUrl`

```kotlin
data class Design(
    val imageUrl: String?
)
```

How can I solve this build error?

Comment: try this
app:imageResource="@{data.imageUrl}"

Comment: I think there's too little code, please provide us with more. It's really hard to understand anything.

Comment: Maybe, resource is expecting integer resId instead of a string?

Comment: have you created a [Binding adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters#custom-logic) for this attribute or not ?

Comment: @YaqoobBhatti Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work...

Comment: @Giorgi Andriadze Thank you for the comment. and I'm sorry for the question with less code. The problem is solved by changing type on binding adapter class. The type was mismuch.

Comment: @ADM Thank you for the answer. Yes, I made binding adapter for ```resource```. This was expecting ```Int```. That is why it was compile error. After changing the type to ```Int```, it worked!!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the answer. I solved this problem. I have Binding adapter class and its type was expecting `Int?`. In other words, `resource` is expecting `Int` so I just need to change type `Int?` to `String`.
Following code was down below

**Before**

```kotlin
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("resource")
    fun ImageView.bindResource(id: Int?) {
       //do something
    }
```

**After**

```kotlin
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("resource")
    fun ImageView.bindResource(id: String?) // Just changed type
     {
       //do something
    }
```